# Use "app access tokens" with the Facebook Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Javascript SDK for a Facebook app and [a certain API call](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/app-game-groups/#set_cover_photo) I want to make, requires an `app access token`. However, [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) states:

> […] app access token should never be hard-coded into client-side code,
>   doing so would give everyone who loaded your webpage or decompiled
>   your app full access to your app secret, and therefore the ability to
>   modify your app. This implies that most of the time, you will be using
>   app access tokens only in server to server calls.

and:

> Note that because this request uses your app secret, it must never be
>   made in client-side code or in an app binary that could be decompiled.
>   **It is important that your app secret is never shared with anyone**.
>   Therefore, this API call should only be made using server-side code.

Emphasis not even mine!
So how the heck am I supposed to make API calls that require app access tokens using the JS SDK if I should only do those calls server-side?

Comment: I will never ever do that! exposing your `app access token` could end up with a complete clone of your app, you have to use server-side scripting

Comment: "Have to"? But then why did Facebook make certain APIs available to the JavaScript SDK at all?

Comment: Facebook created JS-SDK to help developers! but none recommend using app access token in JS

Comment: 2016 and FB JS SDK doesn't require access token just the app id. Post an example where the access token is necessary.

Comment: @Keyne 2019 and v3.3 requires for example to get an url's engagement counters.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: You shouldn't! As Adam wrote, if you expose your app access token, somebody could grab it from the source code and do whatever he wants with it! It's a security issue...

Comment: So how do other developers using the JS SDK do it? Do they really use combinations of APIs? It all seems rather messy (and short-sighted of Facebook).

Comment: I don't think so. the API calls you're mentioning are used to manage groups etc. Why would you implement this just in the frontend?

Comment: I was hoping to use a group's album as a place to store images coming from my app. I get the feeling Facebook really doesn't want me to do that, though.

Comment: Ok, but doesn't your App use some server-side code?

Comment: No, I'm hosting it on Dropbox—hence the reliance on the Javascript SDK.