# How to logout only my application not my facebook account?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using  facebook javascript sdk on my web application.

I am using graph api to login my application

When I logged out from my application,

my application is logout and my facebook account is  also logout.

How to logout only my application not my facebook account ?

Please help me if someone has found solution for this.

this is my code-

```
<script type="text/javascript">     

        var button;
        var userInfo;

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({ appId: '########', 
                status: true, 
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: true,
                oauth: true});

           showLoader(true);

           function updateButton(response) {
                button       =   document.getElementById('fb-auth');
                userInfo     =   document.getElementById('user-info');
                userdata =   document.getElementById('user-data');
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    //user is already logged in and connected
                    FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                        login(response, info);
                    });

                    button.onclick = function() {
                        FB.logout(function(response) {
                            logout(response);
                        });
                    };
                } else {
                    //user is not connected to your app or logged out
                    button.innerHTML = 'Login';
                    button.onclick = function() {
                        showLoader(true);
                        FB.login(function(response) {
                            if (response.authResponse) {
                                FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                                    login(response, info);
                                });    
                            } else {
                                //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
                                showLoader(false);
                            }
                        },                                 {scope:'email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,user_about_me'});   
                    }
                }
            }

            // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
            FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);  
        };
        (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
            e.src = document.location.protocol 
                + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());


        function login(response, info){
            if (response.authResponse) {
                var accessToken                                 =   response.authResponse.accessToken;

                userInfo.innerHTML                             = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + info.id + '/picture">' + info.name
                                                                 + "<br /> Your Access Token: " + accessToken;


        button.innerHTML                               = 'Logout';
                showLoader(false);
                document.getElementById('other').style.display = "block";

            }
        }

        function logout(response){
            userInfo.innerHTML                             =   "";
            document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML     =   "";
            document.getElementById('other').style.display =   "none";
            showLoader(false);
        }

        //stream publish method
        function streamPublish(name, description, hrefTitle, hrefLink, userPrompt){
            showLoader(true);
            FB.ui(
            {
                method: 'stream.publish',
                message: '',
                attachment: {
                    name: name,
                    caption: '',
                    description: (description),
                    href: hrefLink
                },
                action_links: [
                    { text: hrefTitle, href: hrefLink }
                ],
                user_prompt_message: userPrompt
            },
            function(response) {
                showLoader(false);
            });

        }
        function showStream(){
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                //console.log(response.id);
                streamPublish();
            });
        }           

  function share(){
            showLoader(true);
            var share = {
                method: 'stream.share',
                u: 'http://www.appovative.com/'
            };

            FB.ui(share, function(response) { 
                showLoader(false);
                console.log(response); 
            });
        }



        function setStatus(){
            showLoader(true);

            status1 = document.getElementById('status').value;
            FB.api(
              {
                method: 'status.set',
                status: status1
              },
              function(response) {
                if (response == 0){
                    alert('Your facebook status not updated. Give Status Update   Permission.');
                }
                else{
                    alert('Your facebook status updated');
                }
                showLoader(false);
              }
            );
        }

        function showLoader(status){
            if (status)
                document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'block';
            else
                document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Facebook uses Oauth2. The way for *logout* your application is just expiring your current auth token.
Explained in datail at:

[How can I force a facebook access token to expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807122/how-can-i-force-a-facebook-access-token-to-expire)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use your App Access Token in a client-side SDK, because it can be easily extracted from there.

See the discussion here: [Use "app access tokens" with the Facebook Javascript SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737916/use-app-access-tokens-with-the-facebook-javascript-sdk/)

FB itself also strongly discourages this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

> Note that because this request uses your app secret, it must never be
>   made in client-side code or in an app binary that could be decompiled.
>   It is important that your app secret is never shared with anyone.
>   Therefore, this API call should only be made using server-side code.